# Concatenating string variable inside a for loop in the bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file config.ini with the following contents:

```
@ndbd
```

I want to replace `@ndbd` with some other text to finalize the file. Below is my bash script code:

```
ip_ndbd=(108.166.104.204 108.166.105.47 108.166.56.241)

ip_temp=""
for ip in $ip_ndbd
do
    ip_temp+="\n\[ndbd\]\nHostname=$ip\n"   
done
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/\@ndbd/$ip_temp/" /var/lib/mysql-cluster/config.ini
```

Basically, I just want to get all the ip addresses in a specific format, and then replace `@ndbd` with the generated substring.

However, my for loop doesn't seem to be concatenating all the data from `$ip_ndbd`, just the first item in the list.

So instead of getting:

```
[ndbd]
HostName=108.166.104.204 

[ndbd]
HostName=108.166.105.47 

[ndbd]
HostName=108.166.56.241
```

I'm getting:

```
[ndbd]
HostName=108.166.104.204
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to write this, but I don't know how.

I'd appreciate some assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to iterate over an array variable, you need to specify the whole array:

```
ip_ndbd=(108.166.104.204 108.166.105.47 108.166.56.241)

ip_temp=""
for ip in ${ip_ndbd[*]}
do
    ip_temp+="\n\[ndbd\]\nHostname=$ip\n"   
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
ip_ndbd=(108.166.104.204 108.166.105.47 108.166.56.241)
```

with

```
ip_ndbd="108.166.104.204 108.166.105.47 108.166.56.241"
```

Comment: the array is better, you only have to cycle it in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't see any usage of your file with content @ndbd...

is this what you want?

```
kent$  echo "108.166.104.204 108.166.105.47 108.166.56.241"|awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print "[ndbd]";print "HostName="$i;print ""}}'
[ndbd]
HostName=108.166.104.204

[ndbd]
HostName=108.166.105.47

[ndbd]
HostName=108.166.56.241
```

you could just redirect the output to your config.ini file by `> config.ini`